# VBA generating formula via variables

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please help me to fix the formula in the sub. I need to enter dates into it via variables but it always gives me an error '13' data types

I'm talking about the bit:

```
Cells(5, field).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;""bezahlt"";Rawdata!A2:A3446;" >= " & weekstart & "";Rawdata!A2:A3446;" <= " & weekend & "")"
```

The Sub apart from that formula works.....

```
Sub get_cal_weeks()
    Dim weeks As Integer, i As Integer, col As String, weekstart As Date, weekend As Date, calweeks() As Variant
    'start column is D
    col = "D"
    'get amount of weeks
    weeks = countcalweeks()
    'populate array calweeks
    calweeks = fillcalweeks(weeks)
    For i = 0 To weeks
        field = i + i + 4
        weekstart = calweeks(i, 0)
        weekend = calweeks(i, 1)
        Cells(5, field).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;""bezahlt"";Rawdata!A2:A3446;" >= " & weekstart & "";Rawdata!A2:A3446;" <= " & weekend & "")"

    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you convert to long (or double if you need times)

```
Cells(5, field).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;""bezahlt"";Rawdata!A2:A3446;"">=" & CLng(weekstart) & """;Rawdata!A2:A3446;""<=" & CLng(weekend) & """)"
```